# Angular ng read only and location search

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I have html file with angular. I am trying to set an input as read only, if I have a parameter in the URL. Tried something like this but with no success

```
<input type="text" name="firstName"  ng-readonly="$location.search().memRen" />
```

Maybe some solution with ngIf? I am not sure I am new to angular

Comment: `$location` is probably not a variable on the `$scope`

Comment: have you set $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Services are not per definition available on the `$scope` object. Either you have to assign the service on the scope (not recommended!), or add a variable:

```
function myController($scope, $location) {
    $scope.memRen = $location.search().memRen;
}
```

And in your html:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName"
       ng-readonly="memRen" />
```

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain why this answer is downvoted?

Comment: because he is feg vote up please i am new to angular i will accept yours